# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/spi/RegionFactory - When upgrading from spring 3 to spring 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I'm updating my spring project from 3.0.5 to 4.0.3.

Everything's building fine, but at boot time, when spring tries to create beans, I'm hitting this error message:

[image]

The class is of course not present in ehcache-core, hibernate-ehcache, or hibernate-core. In fact, the package `spi` just isn't present anywhere it seems. However, I've checked the maven dependencies, and it seems like spring 4.0.3 and hibernate 3.6.10 should be fully compatible. In my pom I directly depend on hibernate-ehcache, which in turn pulls in the appropriate version of ehcache-core automatically(apparently the done thing), like this:

My dependencies look like:

[image]

[image]

I've searched extensively for this error, but can only find a couple of references to it. Given it's obscurity, I'm guessing it's a configuration within my project somewhere that's referencing this RegionFactory class, however, despite much searching, I can't find a thing.

Any ideas how I can get this project building with spring 4.0.3??

I can provide any additional data you need.

The key is to get the project building against Spring 4.0.3.Release. Whatever version of hibernate or ehcache enables me to do that doesn't really matter. Obviously My preferencs would be pom changes over reconfiguring over changing code... but I'll take what I can get at this point.

EDIT: 
I'm trying to *avoid updating my hibernate past 4.x.y* as this project is very large and uses `HibernateDaoSupport` and `HibernateTemplate` very extensively (thousands of independent usages which would take a long time to refactor)

Comment: Try hibernate version 4.0.1.FINAL, the class you are trying to use seems to have been added in `4.0.0`

Comment: Your dependencies are a bit of a mess. You are mixing Spring 1.2.9 and 4.0.3 and Spring Security 3.2.0 with the old acegi security. I also highly doubt Spring Modules is still working with the new version of Spring (that project is old and abandoned for quite a while).  Can you post your hibernate and caching configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum No argument there. It's a legacy project with lots of technical debt. I think a lot of them aren't even used (although the spring security is deliberate). I'll post the extra info shortly. thnaks.

Comment: @Paul, have the same issue now. How have you fixed it?

Comment: @StasKolodyuk I'm struggling to remember now, but I believe in the end I needed to use a newer version of hibernate -  and by extension Eh-cache - for me that was a massive hassle (because of very extensive use of hibernate template which isn't supported in newer versions of hibernate, and interwoven session-management code that made updating that difficult) , but hopefully for you it's just a simple POM change!

Comment: @Paul, thanks for reply. I am using a 4.3.10.Final version of hibernate now, resolved several issues about hibernate template and eventually everything is fine

Comment: @StasKolodyuk Glad to hear you had an easier time with it than I did! :)

Answer (score 4):

Update the Hibernate Version.

After Hibernate version 4.0.0.Final they chage the package from RegionFactory.

3.6.10.Final:
org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory
4.0.0.Final:
org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid updating my Hibernate version past 4.x.y, as this upgrade breaks HibernateDaoSupport which this project uses very extensively. The documentation seems to imply it works with hibernate 3.6.10.Final?

Comment: HibernateDaoSupport does not have breaks. For use Hibernate 4.x.y have a class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport.

Comment: The HibernateTemplate just doesn't exist in spring 4 as far as I can see? Trying to avoid code changes as much as possible.

Comment: The Spring 4.x.y have a HibernateDaoSupport see here : http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html

Comment: Yes, but no HibernateTemplate, which we have thousands of references to in our code. Any alternative to making 1000s of changes to legacy code is preferable.

Comment: HibernateTemplate also have: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html